# how would I update in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a following Mysql code:

```
update person set name = #{name}, address = #{address}, phoneNumber = #{phoneNumber}
        ,balance = #{balance}, password = #{password} where id = #{id}
```

How would I change the code so that it also updates the "id"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the current id to another id (new_id), the following should work:

```
update person set name = #{name}, address = #{address}, phoneNumber = #{phoneNumber} ,
balance = #{balance}, password = #{password}, id = #{new_id} where id = #{id}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma seperated, just like you've done with the other value updates.